# Blazor Server loses connection for mobile browsers

Tags: api, asp.net-core, signalr, blazor, blazor-server-side

We have set up a Blazor Server side application and encountered an error for the browsers in a mobile phone.

I can unfortunately not contribute with any code but summarize how the error is detected,
the error does not exists for desktop browsers in our case.

**Stack:**

`.NET Core 5.0`

**Flow:**

1. The Blazor application posts data containing an image and an email address.

   - The image is sent as a MemoryStream.
2. The request with data is then sent to an external API that takes care of sending e-mails with images.

   - The image is then read out by opening the request stream.
3. The Blazor application waits for a response until an e-mail has been sent.

**The Exception:**

In a mobile browser (Chrome, Firefox, Edge) the following happens when we try to post data:

- The Blazor application loses contact and needs to be reloaded.
- No e-mail is sent out.

The external API that handles e-mailing throws the following errors:

`"Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"`

**Question:**

Is there any indication that there would be any difference for a mobile browser versus a desktop when making an such a request with Blazor?

Comment: You need to try to collect error messages from the mobile browser - it's easy enough to do. You could be encountering any number of errors - mobile browsers are much more restricted